Shadcn keeps installing dependencies infinitely in Next.js project
I am asking for support related to a problem with shadcn installation. When I try to run the command npx shadcn-ui@latest init, it keeps installing dependencies and no more results for hours.
System parameters:

Windows 11
Node.js 21.7.3

Can anyone help me with this issue?


shadcn depends on external dependencies like radix ui

@cmgchess can you elaborate please?

wait do you mean your installation didnt finish?

@cmgchess Correct. It stays exactly like that for hours. It stops whenever I kill the terminal.

hmm sorry im not sure why it would be hanging :(

@cmgchess I suspect it is a windows 11 problem, but I am not sure.

I confirm that the problem was windows 11.
